# How can I default to a particular printer on a particular wifi network?

Tags: wifi, printing

When I work from the office, I wnt to print from the office printer.

When I work at home, I want to print from my home printer.

But I spend a lot of time sending documents to the last used printer, and then having to re-select the printer.

Is there a way I can set the default printer in OSX to depend on the wifi network I'm currently using?

Comment: Per Apple's documentation about default printers: "your macOS computer remembers the printer you used last at your current network location".  Is your network location set to Automatic?  What macOS version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Catalina, 10.15.3.

Comment: Would still love an answer to this - my machine still always wants to print from the last-used printer and I spend a lot of time deleting documents from the print queue and manually re-selecting the printer! My network location is set to Automatic and I'm now using Big Sur 11.2.1.